# if statement to change textLabel SKColor not executing

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, sprite-kit

I am trying to run an if statement to change the color of a text label in SpriteKit where the number of lives has reached a certain number. But the color is not changing from white to red.

In my Game the Lives decrease by 1  every time an Asteroid passes the Spaceship.

Right now the text label code looks like this:

```
livesLabel.text = "Lives: 3"
livesLabel.fontSize = 70

if livesNumber == 1 {
   livesLabel.fontColor = SKColor.red
} else {
   livesLabel.fontColor = SKColor.white
}

livesLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.right

if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
   switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
   case 2436: // Checks if device is iPhone X
       livesLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.79, y: self.size.height * 0.92)
   default: // All other iOS devices
       livesLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.85, y: self.size.height * 0.95)
   }
}

livesLabel.zPosition = 100
self.addChild(livesLabel)
```

I have a function where a livesNumber if statement works fine which looks like this:

```
func loseALife() {

    livesNumber -= 1
    livesLabel.text = "Lives: \(livesNumber)"

    let scaleUp = SKAction.scale(to: 1.5, duration: 0.2)
    let scaleDown = SKAction.scale(to: 1, duration: 0.2)
    let scaleSequence = SKAction.sequence([scaleUp, scaleDown])

    livesLabel.run(scaleSequence)

    if livesNumber == 0{
        runGameOver()
    }
}
```

If anyone can shed a light on this that would be great. I thought that it might have something to do with String or Int, but since this works on other functions and also I tried some String to Int conversions and it changed nothing I am no longer sure what the issue is.

Comment: What are you seeing now? That the label is always white, or that the label is always red? Also, try adding a breakpoint in your code and step your way through it one line at a time.

Comment: What is the exact issue? color is not changing or conversion of int to string?

Comment: The color stays white. I don’t think a String to Int conversion needed in this case.

Comment: @snapbackdev OK so it seems that `livesNumber` is never equal to 1. Can you add a breakpoint and check that you actually hit this line `if livesNumber == 1 {` . Maybe add a `print` inside your if statement to see if you actually end up inside the if

Comment: Yeah I did the print inside the statement aswell already and it’s not shiwing either. I will try the break point as soon as I get home. Ingame the lives number does go to 1, only the color doesn’t change.

Comment: @snapbackdev OK, the fact that the print is not hit indicates that you do not end up inside the if statement. How is `livesNumber` defined? And where do you decrement it?

Comment: I posted the function where it is decremented.

Comment: it'*s defined in the GameScene.swift as var livesNumber = 3. Which is what the player always starts with. It is then incremented or decremented depending on further actions.

Comment: @snapbackdev ah sorry, I missed that. Then, the code that colors your label, when is that run? It seems you create a label, check if the textcolor should be white or red and then you add the label. But...that seems like a one time operation doesn't it? I mean, something you do once, when your game is initialized. In your case you are interested in changing the color of the label when the `livesNumber` is decremented...not when you setup the label. Or am I misreading your code?

Comment: That actually makes total sense, if I stick this into loseALife function which get's called when losing a life then it would run that function. And then also add it into the addALife function so that when I gain a new life it goes back to white. Or better yet write a function for the color change and just add the function call into each life function. Thanks dude. Can you post that as an answer please so I can green tick it

Comment: @snapbackdev glad we got it figured out. I've added an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen from the discussion above, the problem was that the "color label" code was run once in the initialization of the view. Therefore, when the `livesNumber` value was later updated, the "color label" code wasn't executed.

This can be solved in several ways. One would be to add it to the `looeALife` function:

```
func loseALife() {
    livesNumber -= 1
    livesLabel.text = "Lives: \(livesNumber)"

    if livesNumber == 1 {
        livesLabel.fontColor = SKColor.red
    } else {
        livesLabel.fontColor = SKColor.white
    }

    let scaleUp = SKAction.scale(to: 1.5, duration: 0.2)
    let scaleDown = SKAction.scale(to: 1, duration: 0.2)
    let scaleSequence = SKAction.sequence([scaleUp, scaleDown])

    livesLabel.run(scaleSequence)

    if livesNumber == 0{
        runGameOver()
    }
}
```

(maybe extract it to a separate function)

You could also add a `didSet` to your `livesNumber` and then update the value there:

```
var livesNumber: Int = 3 {
    didSet {
        livesLabel.color = livesNumber == 1 ? .red : .white
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.